# I need help in determining the proper shape of a right triangle with an inscribed square

Tags: geometry, triangles

Is it possible to have a right triangle like in the image, having $BD = CD$ (or $f=e$) and $e \ne d$? [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYzHI.jpg)

I think that it’s only possible to have $BD=CD$ if it (Figure 1) is an isosceles right triangle, but that would make $e=d$.
or have $e \ne d$ but $BD \ne CD $ with a scalene right triangle as in [Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u6l6.jpg)

(I need the largest inscribed square so it touches the hypotenuse)
Please correct me if I am mistaken, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible.  If you require $BDEF$ to be a square, and $BD = CD$, then by similarity of triangles, $\triangle CDE \sim \triangle CBA$, hence $$\frac{AB}{ED} = \frac{BC}{DC} = \frac{BD + DC}{DC} = 2.$$  Consequently $AB = 2ED = 2BF$, which in turn implies $AF = BF = BD = CD$.